# Format stdin in bash

Tags: bash

I have a multi-line string coming from another program that I want to convert to a SQL command.  I was hoping that printf could help me, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
echo -e '1\n2\n3'|printf 'SELECT %s INTO MyTable'
```

I was hoping to see:

```
SELECT '1
2
3' INTO MyTable
```

But I got:

```
SELECT  INTO MyTable
```

How can I get the %s to read stdin?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use *xargs* to transform *stdin* to program arguments:

```
echo -n  -e '1\n2\n3' |xargs -0  printf 'SELECT %s INTO MyTable'
```

Comment: I knew there was a way.  I was just looking at xargs too but couldn't quite piece it together.  This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This would work well, except that bash's printf isn't the same as the /usr/bin/printf executable, which means you can't use "%q". I went with the functional command from @Dennis Williamson

Comment: I got a `value not completely converted` error which was resolved by using `xargs -i printf '%s' {}` instead.

Answer (score 9):

Give this a try:

```
printf_stdin() { local stdin; read -d '' -u 0 stdin; printf "$@" "$stdin"; }

echo -e '1\n2\n3' | printf_stdin 'SELECT %s INTO MyTable'
```

Comment: `printf_stdin() { local stdin; IFS='' read -r -d '' -u 0 stdin; printf "$1" "$stdin"; }` should IMO rather be used. Especially the `IFS=''` (without that I was loosing trailing newlines) and the `-r` (taking `\` literally in the input).

`"$1"` makes more sense than `"$@"`, which would IMO produce rather ambiguous results.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  The `printf` shell command formats its arguments not standard input so what you can do is provide the output of a command as a single argument:

```
bash$ printf "SELECT '%s' INTO MyTable" "`echo -e '1\n2\n3'`"
SELECT '1
2
3' INTO MyTable
bash$
```

**Edit**: a solution in Awk

```
bash$ echo -e '1\n2\n3' | awk -v 'ORS=' '
   BEGIN { print "SELECT \"" }
   { print $0, "\n" }
   END { print "\" INTO MyTable" }'
SELECT "1
2
3
" INTO MyTable
bash$
```

I'll leave stripping the final newline as an exercise to the reader.  If you want to do anything more complex in the `printf`, then you will have to come up with some more creative awk script.

Comment: Is there another command that could work in the order proposed in the question?

Comment: You might be able to get close to the simple `printf` usage in your example with `awk`.  I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @User1, There is a bit of precedent in the *xargs* command. It takes data from stdin and runs commands with the data broken into multiple arguments to a “template” command. You could write a small shell program (e.g. called *1args*) like `s="$(cat)";"$@" "$s"` and use it as `printf '%s\n' 1 2 3 | 1args printf "SELECT '%s' INTO MyTable\n"` to maintain your order. But I am not quite convinced as to its utility. There is a limit to the size of arguments (differs per OS), that will limit how much stdin you might stuff into an argument.